# writing array to serial port c

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I want to write a hex array of bytes to a serial port according to the following guide to communicate with a board.

[image]

my attempt:

```
if((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)) < 0 {
    return;
}
unsigned char command[6] = {0x3E,0x52,0x01,0x53,0x01,0x01};
write(fd,command,6);
sleep(1);
```

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong. Maybe it isn't. What does `write` return? Have you checked for errors? Are there errors? What happens when you fix the missing closing parentheses and build your program and run it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how to check write return value?

Comment: Start by reading the manual page. In a terminal run the command `man write`. Or [look online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are things wrong with it.

1. [`serialOpen()`](http://wiringpi.com/reference/serial-library/) returns -1 if the operation fails, with `errno` set to indicate the error.

   Make sure you include `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<errno.h>`, and `<wiringSerial.h>` at the beginning of your program, and open the serial port using e.g.

   ```
       int fd;

       fd = serialOpen("/dev/ttyS0", 115200);
       if (fd == -1) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open /dev/ttyS0: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
   ```
2. [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) may return a short count. You cannot just assume it sent everything successfully. I recommend you use a helper function, for example

   ```
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif

   int writeall(const int fd, const void *data, const size_t len)
   {
       const char        *ptr = (const char *)data;
       const char *const  end = (const char *)data + len;
       ssize_t            n;

       while (ptr < end) {
           n = write(fd, ptr, (size_t)(end - ptr));
           if (n > 0)
               ptr += n;
           else
           if (n != -1)
               return errno = EIO;
           else
           if (errno != EINTR)
               return errno;
       }

       return 0;
   }

   #ifdef __cplusplus
   }
   #endif
   ```

   which returns 0 for success, and nonzero for errors. You can use it thus:

   ```
       if (writeall(fd, "\x3E\x52\x01\x53\x01\x01", 6)) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Serial write error: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
           /* If this is fatal, do exit(EXIT_FAILURE) here.
              If the error is not a fatal one, let the program continue.
           */
       }
   ```
3. Don't do `sleep()`. At minimum, make sure you include `<termios.h>`, and do

   ```
       tcdrain(fd);
   ```

   to ensure the kernel sends all serial data; it will return only after everything written thus far to `fd` (`fd` being open to a serial port or tty).

Also, I recommend against using `serialPutchar()`, `serialPuts()`, `serialPrintf()`, and `serialGetchar()`, because [they do not have any kind of error checking](https://git.drogon.net/?p=wiringPi;a=blob;f=wiringPi/wiringSerial.c).